# Separating digit in word per word and the last charachter in Java

Tags: java, string

this is my input

> hello world ja123va456789

and i want to get output like this

> hello world ja 123 va 456789

this is my code

```
public String extractDigits(String src) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++) {
        char c = src.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            builder.append(c);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word = "hello world ja123va456789";
    String x = word.trim();
    String[] wordsplit = x.split("\\s+");
    String output = "";
    Coba3 coba = new Coba3();
    for (String word1 : wordsplit) {

        coba.extractDigits(word1);
        output += word1+" ";
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

my ouput is still "hello world ja123va456789", where is the part of my code must be fixed?

Comment: You are not using the returned string from the method extractDigits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may split the input on whitespace or on a lookaround which separates letters from numbers, and then join the parts together:

```
String input = "hello world ja123va456789";
String[] parts = input.split("(\\s+|(?:(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])))");
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        output.append(" ");
    }
    output.append(parts[i]);
}

System.out.println(output);

hello world ja 123 va 456789
```

### Demo